# Example of phenomenon that occurs because Bosons don't obey exclusion principle

Tags: pauli-exclusion-principle, bosons, popular-science

I am writing an essay targeted at undergrad level, non-science audience and I am trying to find another real world example of what is possible due to the fact that bosons are not subject to Pauli exclusion principle, and all I can come up with is lasers.

I should mention that I do not have formal education, just life long self-study of science and physics. I get the concepts, but I don't have the required math.

Comment: Just fundamental bosons, or are you also interested in composite bosons, like Cooper pairs?

Comment: Ah, of course, I wasn't thinking of superconductivity. Can you suggest any examples, other than superconductivity and its applications?

Comment: Bose-Einstein condensation: Bosons tend to be together in the ground state below a certain critical temperature given a certain number density of particles. This is related to so called ‘superfluids’. Look up Helium superfluid, it can penetrate through class for example

Comment: [Hanbury Brown and Twiss effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanbury_Brown_and_Twiss_effect)

Comment: Or how about the fact that light can be bright! If photons were Fermions, you could only every have one quantum of energy in any particular mode of light.

Comment: @DanielSank - thanks, I covered that with lasers, but of course it goes for multi-frequency light as well.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. Much appreciated!

@Dani - I had thought of superfluids, but not a good real life example of how it impacts everyday life.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a request for a list of length 1, which is kinda not suited to the site. The fact that the post was answered in the comments reflects that unsuitability.

Comment: @DanielSank - I do not have an issue with closing it. Is there a more appropriate place to ask a similar question?

Comment: This sort of discussion is good in a [chat room](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat). You only need 20 points to participate in Stack Exchange chat rooms.

Comment: I agree with @PM2Ring